# Corrupted heap while display a BMP image on console

Tags: c++, console, heap-memory, bmp

I have a exercise. It says, that the C program should be able to read the information of a bitmap file and after that it should display the picture on console.

I have already written a code but when it does not work correctly.
When I debugged the code it looks like the heap is corrupted. I thinks I have a known glitch/mistake in `ScanPixelline` function.

I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me to check it?
I am relatively new to C programming.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdint.h"
#include "windows.h"
#pragma pack(1)
struct BMP
{
    char Type[2];           //File type. Set to "BM".
    int32_t Size;     //Size in BYTES of the file.
    int16_t Reserved1;      //Reserved. Set to zero.
    int16_t Reserved2;      //Reserved. Set to zero.
    int32_t OffSet;   //Offset to the data.
    int32_t headsize; //Size of rest of header. Set to 40.
    int32_t Width;     //Width of bitmap in pixels.
    int32_t Height;     //  Height of bitmap in pixels.
    int16_t Planes;    //Number of Planes. Set to 1.
    int16_t BitsPerPixel;       //Number of Bits per pixels.
    int32_t Compression;   //Compression. Usually set to 0.
    int32_t SizeImage;  //Size in bytes of the bitmap.
    int32_t XPixelsPreMeter;     //Horizontal pixels per meter.
    int32_t YPixelsPreMeter;     //Vertical pixels per meter.
    int32_t ColorsUsed;   //Number of colors used.
    int32_t ColorsImportant;  //Number of "important" colors.
};
struct Color
{
    unsigned char B;
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char R;

};
struct ColorTable
{
    Color    *colors;
    unsigned long length;
};

struct PixelArray
{
    Color    **pixels;
    unsigned long rowCount;
    unsigned long columnCount;
};
void readBMP(char *File_Name, BMP &a)
{
    FILE *p = fopen(File_Name, "rb");
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file!");
        fclose(p);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        fread(&a, sizeof(BMP), 1, p);
    }
    fclose(p);
}
void Get_Inf(BMP a)
{
    if (a.Type[0] != 'B' || a.Type[1] != 'M')
    {
        printf("This is not a BMP file");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This is a BMP file\n");
        printf("The size of this file is %lu bytes\n", a.Size);
        printf("The witdth of this image is %lu pixels\n", a.Width);
        printf("The height of this image is %lu pixels\n", a.Height);
        printf("The number of bits per pixels in this image is %u\n", a.BitsPerPixel);
    }

}
void scanBmpPixelLine(Color *&line, unsigned long length)
{
    FILE *pointer_ = fopen("test.bmp", "rb");
    line = new Color[length];
    fread(line, sizeof(Color), sizeof(Color)*length, pointer_);
    fclose(pointer_);
    //file.read((char *)line, length * sizeof(Color));
}
void skipBmpPadding(char count)
{
    FILE *pointer__ = fopen("test.bmp", "rb");
    if (count == 0)
    {
        fclose(pointer__);
        return;
    }
    char padding[3];
    fread(&padding, sizeof(char), count, pointer__);
    fclose(pointer__);
    //file.read((char *)&padding, count);
}
void ReadPixelArray(BMP a, PixelArray &data)
{
    FILE *pointer = fopen("test.bmp", "rb");
    data.rowCount = a.Height;
    data.columnCount = a.Width;
    data.pixels = new Color*[data.rowCount];
    char paddingCount = (4 - (a.Width * (a.BitsPerPixel / 8) % 4)) % 4;
    fseek(pointer, 54, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.rowCount; i++)
    {
        scanBmpPixelLine(data.pixels[data.rowCount - i - 1], a.Width);
        skipBmpPadding(paddingCount);
    }
}
void drawBmp(BMP a, PixelArray data)
{
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(console);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Width; j++)
        {
            Color pixel = data.pixels[i][j];
            SetPixel(hdc, j, i, RGB(pixel.R, pixel.G, pixel.B));
        }

    ReleaseDC(console, hdc);
}

void releaseBmpPixelArray(PixelArray data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.rowCount; i++)
        delete[]data.pixels[i];

    delete[]data.pixels;
}
int main()
{
    char file_name[] = "test.bmp";
    BMP a;
    PixelArray data;
    readBMP(file_name, a);
    Get_Inf(a);
    ReadPixelArray(a, data);
    drawBmp(a, data);
    releaseBmpPixelArray(data);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem like C code. Are you using C++ ?

Comment: `<conio.h>` isn't a standard C header.

Comment: `line = new Color[length];` hints to C++ rather than C. Are you sure you are using the right code here?

Comment: `FILE *pointer_ = fopen("test.bmp", "rb");` This assumes that the file was opened successfully, which is dangerous.

Comment: The first problem is that you cannot read the header with `fread(&a, sizeof(BMP), 1, p);` - you must read each and every field *separately* because they're *unaligned*. Use some debug prints to ensure that the header values are sane (here they wouldn't be)

Comment: It's neither C nor C++, it is Visual Studio goo. As a side note, if you don't even know which programming language you are programming in, there is very little hope in ever achieving a bug-free program.

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
void scanBmpPixelLine(Color *&line, unsigned long length)
{
    FILE *pointer_ = fopen("test.bmp", "rb");
    line = new Color[length];
    fread(line, sizeof(Color), sizeof(Color)*length, pointer_);
    fclose(pointer_);
    //file.read((char *)line, length * sizeof(Color));
}
```

For starters, the intent of the function appears to be to read one line of pixel data from the file.  But instead, it's re-opening the file and reading from the beginning (where the header bytes are). I'm not sure if you are aware of that...

But the crash is a result of this line:

```
    fread(line, sizeof(Color), sizeof(Color)*length, pointer_);
```

The second parameter, sizeof(Color), is the size of each element.  The third parameter is the number of elements to read.  The total bytes read from the file will be the multiplication of the second parameter by the third parameter. So you've redundantly multiplied by `sizeof(Color)` one too many times. The result is that it will overwrite the `line` buffer.

To fix, it should be:

```
fread(line, sizeof(Color), length, pointer_);
```

You probably want to pass the `FILE* pointer` obtained from your `ReadPixelArray` function into this function instead of re-opening the file for every line.

Another code review comment.  You should just read the entire file into memory instead of redundantly opening and closing the file for each operation. Then parse the header and set a pointer to the first "line" after the header.